# Why does Israel question passengers who are departing the country?

Tags: airport-security, israel

Every time I fly out of Israel I am annoyed by the security people asking all kinds of intrusive questions about my trip and where I've been. Every other airport in the world solves the problem by simply checking luggage carefully and maybe asking if "you've packed everything in your bag", which eventually works just as effective;

So what's the point of questioning people who are *exiting* the country?

Comment: On the other hand, probably because of that screening, the rules are more linent, so you can take liquids on board and other small differences.

Answer (score 5):

An attacker could bring down a plane heading both inbound and outbound. While inbound flights are a greater risk as Israel has no control over originating airports, there is no zero-risk of an attack originating from an Israeli airport either.

Checking luggage is insufficient - a plane can be brought down or hijacked with entirely innocuous and permitted luggage (e.g. fake suicide bomb made from duct tape and hot-dogs), to something more elaborate involving corrupt airport staff who could stowaway weapons as they load ordinary cargo.

The intense questioning is part of their evidence-based psychological screening system which I understand is very effective.

Comment: How do other airports handle it though? There are 100x more flights in Europe and they haven't had any successful hijackings for ages.

Comment: > as Israel has no control over originating airports, -- this is not quite true in my experience. Every time I flew into Israel, security was much tighter than normal flights. Munich has a separate hall (1F) for Israel bound flights, Budapest had interviews and sent us suspicious ones to separate bag check. There's always something. Also I think but I can't know that they might try to catch people who in general plan something nefarious not just with the specific plane but this is speculation.

Comment: @JonathanReez Israel believes that it is more under threat than other nations, and therefore takes extra precautions.

Comment: @Chx, this is only for flights by Israeli airlines. Foreign airlines flying tp Israel don't go through that process.

Comment: Especially for travelers who have visited Israeli Arab or Palestinian communities, the interrogations can provide general intelligence: who is approaching tourists, what are they talking about, etc. I had the impression the secondary screeners were not just attractive women doing conscripted army service. (Israel has found that everyone, even other women, talk more freely to attractive young women, which explains why the airport passport examiners all resemble Gal Gadot.) The secondary screeners were older men.

Comment: Let me add that a close friend who had frequent International NGO business in the West Bank believed that he was interrogated for hours at Ben Gurion exit every time as a way of discouraging his participation in the project.